# geo-autocomplete jquery + google maps

Tags: jquery, google-maps

In this plugin [geo-autocomplete](http://geo-autocomplete.googlecode.com/svn-history/r16/trunk/demo/ui.demo.html), why when I type "New" start of "New York" he's not show anything?

Comment: do u check console is it shows any error?

Comment: try this link https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete

Comment: Thank you about this. Are you know how can I change the format of the address that return from google (NY, New York, Usa) insted (New York, NY)